# 404 error when calling from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, http-status-code-404

When the page is redirected to this URL, I get a 404 response. The file location is okay. I have already tried with an absolute path, but that doesn't work.

This is URL:

`window.location.href = "../modules/ajax/Save_prix_fournisseur.php?tab_f1_cas4=" + prix_f1_cas4 + "&tab_f2_cas4=" + prix_f2_cas4 + "&tab_f3_cas4=" + prix_f3_cas4 + "&tab_f4_cas4=" + prix_f4_cas4 + "&tab_f1_cas5=" + prix_f1_cas5 + "&tab_f2_cas5=" + prix_f2_cas5 + "&tab_f3_cas5=" + prix_f3_cas5 + "&tab_f4_cas5=" + prix_f4_cas5 + "&tab_f5_cas5=" + prix_f5_cas5 + "&tab_f1_cas6=" + prix_f1_cas6 + "&tab_f2_cas6=" + prix_f2_cas6 + "&tab_f3_cas6=" + prix_f3_cas6 + "&tab_f4_cas6=" + prix_f4_cas6 + "&tab_f5_cas6=" + prix_f5_cas6 + "&tab_f6_cas6=" + prix_f6_cas6;`

Comment: It could be that your webserver doesn't allow HTML clients to access files in the modules/ajax directory

Comment: Hi Peter. I have other script who acces to this folder and it's work.

Comment: Are you sure all the values are calculated before you try to use them ? Since it's javascript, you might have troubles because it's asynchron

Comment: So given a URL relative to an **unknown** URL generated with variables using **unknown** variables the server running **unknown** server side code with an **unknown** configuration and an **unknown** file system structure resolves it as 404. What do you expect us to be able to do about it?

Comment: "The file location is okay" — Since the server says "not found" I doubt that statement is correct.

Comment: @kazu Yes all values is calculated. With other script, the same path work

Comment: Can you try to make a field and display it, that has the exact value of what you are trying to put in the location.href, with all prix_fX_casY, and display it ? If any prix_fX_casY is replaced by **unknown** in here, it means they are not calculated before you try to use them.

Comment: @kazu : This link work great : ../modules/ajax/Save_prix_fournisseur.php?tab_f1_cas4={"6800697":"2.00","6800703":"56.00","6827239":"0.00","6886652":"0.00"}&tab_f2_cas4={"6800697":"2.00","6800703":"1.00","6827239":"0.00","6886652":"0.00"}&tab_f3_cas4={"6800697":"2.00","6800703":"5.00","6827239":"0.00","6886652":"0.00"}&tab_f4_cas4={"6800697":"2.00","6800703":"3.00","6827239":"0.00","6886652":"0.00"}

Comment: Well at least we're sure it's not a async problem ! That's a good start. Did you define any routes somewhere ? Maybe that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

404 means file not exists

403 means doesn't allow to access

please follow [http status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

**my advice is check the url ../modules/ajax/Save_prix_fournisseur.php**

Comment: It's impossible, I don't know urs config. It's must be file path questions